# Javascript doesn't clear submitted values after each action

Tags: javascript

I have a simple table like this:

```
<td> <span class='foo' onclick='insertComment(this)' data-id='1' </span> </td>
<td> <span class='foo' onclick='insertComment(this)' data-id='2' </span> </td>
<td> <span class='foo' onclick='insertComment(this)' data-id='3' </span> </td>
```

And I am using something like this function to submit the data via ajax POST

```
function insertComment(div){
    // grab the data-id
    var id =  $(div).data('id');


    // open modal
    $(div).attr("data-toggle", "modal")
    $(div).attr("data-target", "#modal-for-quote-" + type); 


    // get input value from modal
    var input = document.getElementById("username-input").value;


    // check if submit btn on modal is clicked

    var btn = document.querySelector('.submit-btn'); 
    btn.onclick = function(){

    var dataString = 'id=' + id + '&input=' + input; 
    // send ajax post
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        url:  "http://example.com/ajax.php", 
        data: dataString,
        success: function(response){

        }
    })
  }

}
```

The problem thing is, when I click on the the rows a modal opens up, and I insert data into the modal and the value gets submitted into my db. This works as intended, but I only if I refresh the page after each submit.

However, if I just keep clicking the three rows and inserting value, the second and third clicks contain more than one value.

Here is what `dataString` contains on my first submit

```
// id=1&input=something
```

On second click

```
// id=1&input=something
// id=2&input=something
```

On third click

```
// id=1&input=something
// id=2&input=something
// id=3&input=something
```

All of these are just one click after the other and js is supposed to send only one post request at a time, but somehow after the first click, it seems everything is stored somewhere

Comment: I can't see anything that would append old values to `dataString`. I think the problem is in code you haven't shown, like the `success:` function.

Comment: The `success:` only returns the result, They are more like the last output I have shown

Comment: You need to use `.value` to get the value of an input when assigning to `input`.

Comment: `var dataString = 'id=' + id + '&input=' + input;` should be `var dataString = 'id=' + id + '&input=' + input.value;

Comment: Yeah, sorry that was my mistake.  The code is bigger than this, so I had to write this one here

Comment: I still don't see anything that would keep values from previous calls. We need to see more code.

Comment: You're using `.value` before the user clicks the submit button, so you don't get the value that the user entered.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the value of the input in the `onclick` function. You're setting `input` before the user has had a chance to enter anything into the input field. I'm not sure why this is resulting in accumulating parameters, I suspect it's in the code you still haven't shown.

I also recommend using an object instead of a string for the `data` parameter to `$.ajax`. jQuery will then encode it properly.

```js
function insertComment(div) {
  // grab the data-id
  var id = $(div).data('id');

  // open modal
  $(div).attr("data-toggle", "modal")
  $(div).attr("data-target", "#modal-for-quote-" + type);

  // get input value from modal
  var input = document.getElementById("username-input");

  // check if submit btn on modal is clicked

  var btn = document.querySelector('.submit-btn');
  btn.onclick = function() {
    var dataString = {
      id: id,
      input: input.value
    };
    // send ajax post
    jQuery.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "http://example.com/ajax.php",
      data: dataString,
      success: function(response) {

      }
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I recommend to you use next solution:

```
success: function(response){
  window.reload()
}
```

It will reload your page after each click.
For better user experience, make your button unactive, after click, it helps reduce unexpected multiclicking and data send. Hope it helps!

Comment: This didn't help. The page is not reloading.